# Read characters from an object property

Tags: javascript

is it possible to access/read object properties as strings?

Let´s say I have the following code:

```
var dog = {
    name: 'Rex'
}
```

And I want to get the first 2 characters of the dog.name(should be 'Re). If name would be a variable, I would simply access it via the charachter position( name[0], name[1] ). Is something like this possible with properties, without converting them or storing dog.name in another variable?

Comment: your object is invalid

Comment: @RomanPerkhrest fixed

Answer (score 3):

First, the object must be like this:

```
var dog = {
  name:'Rex'
}
```

The easiest way to get the first 2 characters of your name property is like this: `dog.name.substring(0, 2); //returns 'Re'`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access them using:

```
dog.name[0]
```

or

```
dog["name"][0]
```

And you can access the 2 first letters using:

```
dog.name.slice(0,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do dog.name[0].

And javascript object properties are initialized with ":", so instead of

`var dog = {
    name = 'Rex'
}`

You should do

`var dog = {
    name : 'Rex'
}`

Answer (score 0):

Correct your object syntax first by replacing the '=' with an ':' like:

```
var dog = {
name: 'Rex'
}
```

Then you can do:

```
var res = dog.name.substring(0, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

To access a property you have 2 possibilities :

- Using dot notation `dog.name`
- Using brackets notation `dog['name']`

After that you can use the result as you want

`dog.name[0]` will give you `R` - the first character

`dog.name.substring(0, 2)` will give you `Re` - the first 2 characters

```js
var dog = {
    name: 'Rex'
};

console.log(dog.name);
console.log(dog['name']);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var dog = {
     name:"Rex"
}
var result = dog.name.substring(0,2)
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer]. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5244995)